# plot a R plotly graph based on date range input

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, plotly, r-plotly

I have a plotly graph like this. Here I will be adding a daterange input. Based on this selection I need to re plot the graph.

Sample data

```
dates    ex   act
NOV-17   77    90
DEC-17   98    78 
JAN-18   65    87
FEB-18   77    54
MAR-18   44    34
```

Sample code :

```
   age <- plot_ly(data_, x = ~dates, y = ~ex, name = 'Expect', type = 'scatter',mode = 'lines+markers',
                                line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
        add_trace(y =~act , name = 'Actual',mode = 'lines+markers', line = list(color = 'rgb(170, 255, 102)', width = 4)) %>%
        layout(title = "Mon vs KM",
               xaxis = list(title = "Mon"),
               yaxis = list (title = "KM"),
               legend = list(orientation = 'h'))
```

IF my selection is `2017-12-01 to 2018-03-01` then my X axis should be from `DEC-17 to MAR-18`

I know to code I just need to know how to filter x axis

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: First thing I would say, is make sure your `dates` variable is in the correct format. I don't think R will recognize what to do with your variable. Secondly, what's your question? Do you want help in coding this in a Shiny app? If so, can you provide your code for the shiny app

Comment: You'd increase your chances for an answer a lot if you would provide a reproducible example: I would post the following code:

1) libraries you used
2) how to generate the data
3) sample code, which could be run together with steps 1) and 2).

Comment: I know to code I just need to know how to filter x axis

Comment: You'll need to use something similar to this in your Ui: `dateRangeInput("date","Date:", label = h4("Time Series: select dates"),start = "2017-11-01",end =                                                                            "2018-03-01", min = "2017-11-01",max = "2018-03-01", startview = "month",                                                                                  language = "en", format="yyyy-mm-dd")
           )`

Comment: You'll need to generate a reactive dataset using something like this: 
      `reactiveTime <- reactive({
         data %>% filter(dates>=input$date[1] & dates<input$date[2])
       })` this will go in your server output

Comment: it is obvious that you know to code perfectly well. for people wanting to help it is easier to start with a full example, which can be c+p and runs. otherwise someone needs to setup the example by himself before testing if the solution works. it would also be helpful to know what you've tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: Agree with @huan, I'd like to help more specifically, but can't really do that in a comments section and I don't want to committ to an answer without knowing exactly what the code is like

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

PS: You should be careful using abbreviations of the names of months since they are locale-specific.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plotly - dateRangeInput"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput(inputId="myDateRange", label="", start = NULL, end = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("age")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_ <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                      dates = c("NOV-17", "DEC-17", "JAN-18", "FEB-18", "MAR-18"),
                      ex = c(77L, 98L, 65L, 77L, 44L),
                      act = c(90L, 78L, 87L, 54L, 34L))

  data_$helperDates <- as.Date(paste0(data_$dates, "-01"), format="%b-%y-%d")

  data_ <- data_[order(data_$helperDates, decreasing = FALSE), ]
  data_$dates <- factor(data_$dates, levels = c(as.character(data_$dates)))

  minDate <- min(data_$helperDates, na.rm = TRUE)
  maxDate <- max(data_$helperDates, na.rm = TRUE)
  updateDateRangeInput(session, inputId="myDateRange", start = minDate, end = maxDate, min = minDate, max = maxDate)

  filteredData <- reactive({
    req(input$myDateRange)
    na.omit(data_[data_$helperDates >= input$myDateRange[1] & data_$helperDates <= input$myDateRange[2], ])
  })


  output$age <- renderPlotly({

    req({nrow(filteredData()) > 0})

    age <- plot_ly(filteredData(), x = ~dates, y = ~ex, name = 'Expect', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
                   line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
      add_trace(y =~act, name = 'Actual', mode = 'lines+markers', line = list(color = 'rgb(170, 255, 102)', width = 4)) %>%
      layout(title = "Mon vs KM",
             xaxis = list(title = "Mon"),
             yaxis = list (title = "KM"),
             legend = list(orientation = 'h'))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```