# extract shiny daterangeinput data

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, date-range, shiny-reactivity

I need to extract year and month from shiny daterangeinput. I tried :

```
output$sampled <- renderText({
    x <- as.character(format(input$daterange[1], "%Y"))
    })
```

But I am getting `NULL`. I need to get like `2018-08`

Answer (score 0):

You will need `"%Y-%m"` instead of `"%Y"`.

See `?strptime` to get an overview of the implemented conversion specifications (platform-specific).

But I suspect there is something else wrong in your code when you are getting `NULL`, normally it should return the year only (I'd need a rep. example to dig deeper).

Btw. have you seen my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733659/9841389) here? - If it's still about the same problem?

Comment: I tired but I am getting 18-02 18-04 etc not 2018-02 2018-04

Comment: Make sure to use uppercase Y: %Y
Year with century | %y - Year without century (00–99)